# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons not showing on rails production server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, glyphicons

I am unable to load **Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons** fonts on my live server which are working perfectly on my local server but not on live server.

I have tried each and everything from SO to everything but it still didnt work for me.

Here is what I am doing:

applicatin.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import 'home';
@import "bootstrap";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
    src: url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import 'home';
@import "bootstrap";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
    src: url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
}
```

and

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import 'home';
@import "bootstrap";

@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

and

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import 'home';
@import "bootstrap";

@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

and

```
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import 'home';
@import "bootstrap";
```

and

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import 'home';
@import "bootstrap";
```

but all of them didn't work for me but they are fine on local server.

Comment: when you specified the `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css`, did you precompile the assets after that?

Comment: No, I didnt precompile them on live server. Isnt anything happen to my server if I does this? This is my live site

Comment: There should not be any issue on the production server, compile the assets locally by `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets precompile` and the update and check on staging environment. and then update the code on production

Comment: I'm not sure why you're manually adding all these unnecessary @import statements. You seem to be loading Bootstrap from CDN, and since that is the case all you need is to stylesheet_link_tag it in you application.scss and then rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production and you're good to go. possibly a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239842/rails-4-using-cdn-in-production

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the asset pipeline getting in your way...

Please follow these steps to fix it:

1. Copy font files <kbd>glyphicons-halflings-regular.*</kbd> to the folder <kbd>you-app-path/vendor/assets/fonts</kbd>
2. Copy file <kbd>boostrap.css</kbd> to folder <kbd>you-app-path/vendor/assets/stylesheets</kbd>
3. Rename copied file <kbd>boostrap.css</kbd> to <kbd>boostrap.css.erb</kbd>
4. Edit file <kbd>boostrap.css.erb</kbd> adjusting the <kbd>@font-face</kbd> variable as follows:
   `@font-face {
     font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
     src: url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')%>');
     src: url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')%>?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2')%>') format('woff2'),
     url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')%>') format('woff'),
     url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')%>') format('truetype'),
     url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg')%>#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
   }`
5. Add/adjust the following line in file <kbd>you-app-path/config/initializers/assets.rb</kbd>:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.svg *.eot *.woff *.woff2 *.ttf)
```

6. add this line to file <kbd>you-app-path/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss</kbd>:

```
*= require bootstrap
```

7. and finally, <kbd>restart</kbd> your rails app and all should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can place all you fonts in a folder `#{Rails.root}/public/fonts` folder and change your code according to the following.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
  }
```

Comment: How can I have physical fonts folder? from where I need to download them? you can see its part of bootstrap in which these all resides.

Comment: You get all bootstrap fonts at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ . Place the fonts folder in the public folder of rails project and change the font path accordingly

Answer (score 0):

do these changes

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

And if again not loading any other Glyphicons then change its path `../fonts/` and it will get resolved

Comment: `../fonts/ ` to what path? please explain?

Comment: It says: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://lvh.me:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"`
and
`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://lvh.me:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"`

Comment: it works on local: `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}` would that work on production well?? thats my question.

Comment: I have this in my bootstrap.min.css
`@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),url(/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),url(/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg')}`

And this code work well in development and prod also ...do changes accordingly

Comment: Did you place fonts folder in directory and where?

Comment: Dir structure will be 
app -> Assets -> - fonts, javascripts, stylesheets,images

I am using what rails by default provides.

Comment: thank you so much. and how to get `fonts` folder? i know from bootstrap but link please?

Comment: in config/application.rb add line
`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms that were caused by a CORS issue with my CDN. Was obvious once I finally opened my browser's JavaScript console.